# Selecting and plotting the solution that meets certain conditions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have this equation of order 6, which mean there will be 6 solution of a in term of v

[image]

```
Solve[
  a^6 - 8 a^4 + 8 (3 - (1 - 2 ν)/(1 - ν)) a^2 - 16 (1 - (1 - 2 ν)/(2 (1 - ν))) == 0, 
  a]
```

I would like to plot only the real solution where `0 < a < 1` as a function of `ν`, and discard all other solutions.

I would like the plot to be a list plot.

Comment: The Details&Options section of [the documentation of `Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) will show you how to restrict your solutions to the `Reals` domain. You can also use a list of equations and inequalities as the first argument of `Solve`. Perhaps those will help.

Comment: It is much better to pas Mathematica code than an image. From an image one can not copy and past the code and has to key in the (your) code.

Comment: Note that your equation is cubic in $a^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May not be what the OP wants exactly, but this is too big for a comment:

The following does plot the solution obtained with a restricted to be between 0 and 1. Nu is taken to be between -1 and 1 in steps of 0.1. Note that there could be no solutions for certain values of Nu.

```
Table[
  {k, 
   First @ 
     Select[
       Flatten[
         With[{ν = k}, a /. 
           Solve[
             a^6 - 8 a^4 + 8 (3 - (1 - 2 ν)/(1 - ν)) a^2 - 16 (1 - (1 - 2 ν) / 
               (2 (1 - ν))) == 0, 
             a]]], 
       0 <= # <= 1 &]
  }, 
  {k, -1, 1, 0.1}]

ListPlot[%]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: it can be done also without `Table`: `sol[ν_] = a /. Solve[a^6 - 8 a^4 + 8 (3 - (1 - 2 ν)/(1 - ν)) a^2 - 16 (1 - (1 - 2 ν)/(2 (1 - ν))) == 0 && 0 < a < 1, a, Reals]`, then `Plot[Evaluate@sol[ν], {ν, -1, 1}]` gives two curves: one from negative values to about 0.27, the other from that 0.27 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

`Solve` can impose your conditions directly:

```
Solve[
  {a^6 - 8 a^4 + 8 (3 - (1 - 2 ν)/(1 - ν)) a^2 - 16 (1 - (1 - 2 ν)/(2 (1 - ν))) == 0,
   0 < a < 1},
  a, Reals
];

Plot[Evaluate[a /. %], {ν, -30, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> 0]
```

Here I used colored filling to highlight the domain of each of the two solutions.

[image: plot of the two solutions]